# Aks is not connecting with keyvault when autoscaling is enabled. We used aks pool identity for connecting Keyvault

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Issue:
We have deployed AKS from ARM template with managed identity by using default Kubnet. Auto scaling is disabled while deploying. we have deployed cluster with two node configuration..
Recently one of our Node utilisation reached 95%. We have given a Pod replica as 1. So pod is present on a single node only. To over come this problem we tried to enable autoscaling of node and kept Node min as2 and max as 5. All these autoscaling is enabled from portal.
Main Issue is when we enable autoscaling the agentpool identity system assigned managed identity is getting disabled Refer pic 1. Due to which we are not able to connect with key vault.

When ever the Node gets scaled the ASK pool identity system managed is getting disabled.
We are using AKS pool System Managed Identity and adding in keyvault access policy. Then we can get values from Keyvault. But when the node is auto scaling system managed identity is getting disabled. So keyvault connection is getting break. Is there any way to connect automatically even autoscales the node?

Comment: I would look for other culprits: Are any ARM templates running against your AKS cluster on a regular basis that would be disabling system identity?

Comment: No. When we enable autoscaling AKS vmss agent pool System Identity is getting disabled. How to use User assigned identity to link aks and Keyvault by user assigned identity